# Laravel 8: Missing required parameter for Route

Tags: laravel-routing

I keep getting this error when i try to edit anything.
`Missing required parameter for [Route: updat.e] [URI: edit/{id}] [Missing parameter: id].`
Here is my view:
  `<form action="{{ route('update',$zlecenie->id ) }}" method="post">`
Controller:

```
public function edit(Zlecenia_model $zlecenie){

  return view('edit')->with('zlecenie', $zlecenie);

}

public function update(Request $request, Zlecenia_model $zlecenie){
  $zlecenie->update([
    'status' => $request->status,
    'id_klienta' => $request->id_klienta,
    'marka' => $request->marka,
    'model' => $request->model,
    'numer_seryjny' => $request->numer_seryjny,
    'informacje_zleceniodawcy' => $request->informacje_zleceniodawcy,
    'informacje_zleceniobiorcy' => $request->informacje_zleceniobiorcy,

  ]);
  return redirect()->route('index')->with('success', 'Nadpisano zlecenie');
}
```

And Routing:

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Zlecenia_controller::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');
Route::post('/edit/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Zlecenia_controller::class, 'update'])->name('update');
```

Comment: try `route('update', ['id' => $zlecenie->id])`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

Comment: still not working, same error :/